# Subpath without leading '.'

Tags: powershell-core

I'm trying to find a way to produce qualified names of sub-paths sans the leading "./", for all directories under my current location:

```
$dirs = Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse .
```

I'd use `Resolve-Path -Relative` but the next place I need the result is as a string without the `./`.

Without resorting to string-manip shenanigans (I could -split each path, slice away the first element and thenjoin-path it back together again, but yuk!)

Note: I'm using this cross-platform, so any solution needs to work under core.

---- Edit: Examples ----

Linux:

```
> cd /proc/sys
> Function GetIPV6 { gci -r -dir |? name -eq 'ipv6' }
> GetIPV6 | Resolve-Path -Relative
./net/ipv6    # << has a leading './' I want to avoid
> (GetIPV6).FullName
/proc/sys/net/ipv6   # << full path, not sub path
```

What I'm looking for is:

```
> cd /proc/sys
> GetIPV6 | ???
net/ipv6
```

Windows:

```
> cd /windows/system32
> Function GetETC { gci -r -dir |? name -eq "etc" }
> GetETC | resolve-path -relative
.\Drivers\etc  #< has leading .\
> (GetETC).FullName
C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc  #< full path
```

What I want is

```
> GetETC | ???
Drivers\etc   or Drivers/etc
```

Comment: Adding the `powershell` tag since this isn't strictly a *Core* issue.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Except I only want a core solution, so I'll remove the tag again and edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand *qualified paths* as *fully-qualified paths*, there is a `FullName` property on the `System.IO.DirectoryInfo` object that is returned from `Get-ChildItem -Directory`:

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
```

This gives you a string array of all the fully-qualified paths for directories under your working directory.

---

To address your edit, this example will work on *nix or Windows:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse).
    FullName.
    Replace("$pwd", '') -replace '^[\\/]'
```

Finally a more powershell way:

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName |
    % Replace "$pwd/", ''
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm looking for the *sub*path I would get from `Resolve-Path -Relative` but without the leading `./`. This answer just gets me the full path.

`cd /proc ; gci -R -Dir |? name -eq "ipv6" | select-object -exp fullname` => `/proc/sys/net/ipv6` <-- not what I need
`cd /proc ; gci -R -Dir |? name -eq "ipv6" | resolve-path -rel` => `./sys/net/ipv6` => don't want leading `./`
`cd /proc ; gci -R -Dir | ???` => `sys/net/ipv6`?

Comment: So, you don't know of a way to do this without resorting to string manipulation? (one of the stipulations of the question for all but the last edit)

Comment: @kfsone correct. There is no property on a returned object that has the relative information in the format you want it.